# Loop untill random name matches my spesified name [Python]

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to let the computer choose randomly between the letters until it matches my name. Each time it fails to match, it prints the wrong name and continue automatically until it matches the correct name.

```
import random
myName='husam'
while(myname!=name):
    def generator():
        letter1 = random.choice('hu')
        letter2 = random.choice('us')
        letter3 = random.choice('sa')
        letter4 = random.choice('ua')
        letter5 = random.choice('hm')
        name = letter1 +letter2+letter3+letter4+letter5
        return(name)
print(generate())
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you open to changes? You could easily do it by randomizing from a list.

```
import random
list = ["hu","us","sa","ua","hm",]
name = "husa"
while True:
    x = random.choice(list) + random.choice(list)
    print(x)
    if x == name:
        break
```

Tested a couple of times. Gives you the following outputs:

```
ushu
huua
husa
husa
>>> 

huus
uaua
husa
>>> 

huua
saua
sahu
ushm
sasa
uahu
huua
huus
huhm
uahm
uaua
saus
hmua
uahu
husa
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks alot.
------------------
import random,string
name = "husam"
while True:
    x1 = random.choice('h')
    x2 = random.choice('u')
    x3 = random.choice('s')
    x4 = random.choice('a')
    x5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x=x1+x2+x3+x4+x5
    print(x)
    if x == name:
        break